# Android studio attribute has already been difined

Tags: android, attributes, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

This is my first time use Android studio. I created new project and some sopport libraries and Google play service. Now I want to import one GitHub example in my project:

https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon

When I run my app Android studio is showing an error:

[image: error]

I searched for information about this error but I was unable to solve my problem.

Comment: From your `logcat`, it shows that you use multi times of `access_network_state` at your `AndroidManifest` file at line both 7 and 20. You should delete one of them.

Comment: @bjiang ideleted it but still i have problem

Comment: What kind of problem? Still the same?